# HTML Split the <input type="checkbox> from the overflow wrapped text

Tags: html, css

I am working on writing up a form and it has a bunch of paragraphs that have a checkbox in front of the first word of the paragraph. The problem is that when the text reaches the end of the line and wraps to the next line, it starts the next line under the checkbox. How do I get it to aligned with the first word of the paragraph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the possibilies of a [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox).

```css
p {
  margin: 0 0 0 1rem;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="container" >
   <div style="display:flex">
   <input type="checkbox">
   <p style="display:contents">11I am working on writing up a form and it has a bunch of paragraphs that have a checkbox in front of the first word of the paragraph. The problem is that when the text reaches the end of the line and wraps to the next line, it starts the next line under the checkbox. How do I get it to aligned with the first word of the paragraph? </p>
   </div>
   <div style="display:flex">
   <input type="checkbox">
   <p style="display:contents">22I am working on writing up a form and it has a bunch of paragraphs that have a checkbox in front of the first word of the paragraph. The problem is that when the text reaches the end of the line and wraps to the next line, it starts the next line under the checkbox. How do I get it to aligned with the first word of the paragraph? </p>
   </div>
   <div style="display:flex">
   <input type="checkbox">
   <p style="display:contents">33I am working on writing up a form and it has a bunch of paragraphs that have a checkbox in front of the first word of the paragraph. The problem is that when the text reaches the end of the line and wraps to the next line, it starts the next line under the checkbox. How do I get it to aligned with the first word of the paragraph? </p>
   </div>
</div>
```

You can do something like this.